# How to fix the error using Find function in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to search a value from another sheet rather using the .FIND function

```
Private Function Search(rng As Range, FindString As String) As Range
    With rng
        Set Search = .Find(what:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        lookat:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
     End With
```

The funny  thing is that if I enter

```
Search(Range("'DataSheet'!A1:Z1000"),"STARTING")
```

It works. When I try

```
 SearchString = "'" & Selected_sheet &"'!A1:Z1000"
```

It does not work Selected_sheet is just a name of a worksheet (In this case, it is "DataSheet"). Using

```
Search(Range(SearchString ),"STARTING") 

Error: RUN-TIME ERROR '91'
Object variable or With Block Varibale Not Set
```

What could be the actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is not incorrect but I recommend not passing your range like that.

Use this

```
Search(Sheets("DataSheet").Range("A1:Z1000"),"STARTING")
```

or

```
Selected_sheet = "DataSheet"
Search(Sheets(Selected_sheet).Range("A1:Z1000"),"STARTING")
```

BTW there is nothing wrong with `Range(SearchString)` in your code. It should work. How are you calling `Search`? Hope like this?

```
Dim Ret As Range '<~~~

Selected_sheet = "DataSheet"
SearchString = "'" & Selected_sheet & "'!A1:Z1000"
Set Ret = Search(Range(SearchString), "STARTING")
```

**Reason**: The function returns a `Range` so you cannot just call it without `Set Ret = ...` Where `Ret` is again declared as a `Range`.

**EDIT**

You can also get that error if your `Search` function doesn't return a range and you try using that `Ret`. See this example.

```
Dim Ret As Range

Selected_sheet = "DataSheet"
SearchString = "'" & Selected_sheet & "'!A1:Z1000"
Set Ret = Search(Range(SearchString), "STARTING")

'<~~ This will give you RUN-TIME ERROR '91' if "STARTING" is not found
Debug.Print Ret.Address
```

So how do we tackle this

Try this

```
Dim Ret As Range

Selected_sheet = "DataSheet"
SearchString = "'" & Selected_sheet & "'!A1:Z1000"
Set Ret = Search(Range(SearchString), "STARTING")

If Not Ret Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print Ret.Address
Else
    Debug.Print "Search Didn't return any results"
End If
```

Comment: I very much appreciate the details explanation on the issue. I try the last one and it works. I did use "SET" on mine, I think I should have need to handle the error in case no value found.