# How to resize the new range from two return range of FIND function in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In my [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092433/how-to-fix-the-error-using-find-function-in-excel-vba) I have ask how to handle the return range of .FIND function in Excel. Now I would like to have a new range which is a result of calling SEARCH Function to find "BEGIN" and "STOP"

[image]

I tried

```
Set New_Range = Sheets(Selected_sheet).Range(Begin_RANGE).Resize(Stop_RANGE.Row, 0)
```

Which Begin_RANGE and Stop_Range are set to be to return value of SEARCH.

```
Private Function Search(rng As Range, FindString As String) As Range
    With rng
        Set Search = .Find(what:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        lookat:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
     End With
```

Comment: You can use the resize property of range. Kindly refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193274.aspx

Comment: For continuous range from `start` to `stop` use this: `.... = Sheets(Selected_sheet).Range(Begin_RANGE, Stop_PRANGE)`...

Answer (score 0):

In your try you set the column resize to 0 and this will error. What you need to do is either discretely note the number of columns as 1 or simply leave this out e.g.:

```
Set New_Range = Sheets(Selected_sheet).Range(Begin_RANGE).Resize(Stop_RANGE.Row)
```

But I would try and eliminate any potential issues of the beginning cell not being in row 1 but take its difference like so:

```
Set New_Range = Sheets(Selected_sheet).Range(Begin_RANGE).Resize(Stop_RANGE.Row - Begin_RANGE.Row + 1)
```

And **remember** when using the `resize` function the numbers you put in it are the resulting size.